Concatenate not working as per slicer selection in tree map visual
In the tree map visual, in a category, using calculated column which concatenated project name and associate count per project.
After selecting the slicer start date or end date in treemap, the count does not change in visual
Visual should display Level 6(1) its display static count not change dynamically.
Need Output in tree Map:
In tree map visual "Project(Count of name) count of name change as per slicer dynamically.

what does level 6(1) mean? only one project for level 6? what if the start date is 21st Sep? what's the expected output? What will the end date affect the output? could you pls also elaborate this as well?

Hi Ryan, Level 6 is Project name and only 1 project for level 6 on start date for 21st sep and end also needs to affects output. Kindly refer above date view image for reference. Expected output is whenever apply start or end date filter in tree map needs to change project names and as well count. I created calculated column for concatenating the Project & Count of name.

@VishnuLA - slicers don't affect calculated columns. You must use measures instead.
